# How to set up a different pager and color mode in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, diff, pager, hgrc

I set up Mercurial in `.hgrc` to use `less` as a pager together with customized colors and templates following [this guide](http://jordi.inversethought.com/blog/customising-mercurial-like-a-pro/):

```ini
[pager]
pager = LESS='FSrX' less

[templates]
# ...

[color]
mode=terminfo
```

This works very nicely and I'd like to keep this for all commands except for `hg diff`. For this command only I'd like to use a completely different mechanism:

- No ANSI escape codes in output.
- Use https://github.com/dandavison/delta as a pager.

Is it possible to configure Mercurial this way?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution [here](https://github.com/dandavison/delta/discussions/1045#discussion-4008791) which achieves this setup using the [`extdiff` extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ExtdiffExtension).

```ini
[extensions]
hgext.extdiff =

[extdiff]
cmd.delta =

[alias]
diff = delta
```

---

Earlier I had this workaround - to create a separate alias:

```ini
[alias]
d = !$HG diff "$@" | delta
```

Unfortunately it's not possible to replace the original `diff` command this way. While it's possible (although [discouraged](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/hgrc.5.html#alias)) to replace a command with an alias, in this case it doesn't work: Invoking `$HG diff` from a `diff` alias would cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Note that you'll need to use `opts.delta` (right under the line `cmd.delta` if you want to pass any command-line flags to delta. I had to do `opts.delta = --width=100` to get it to not incorrectly linewrap

Answer (score 3):

- Beware of using manuals for Mercurial from 2014 in 2022, they can be outdated and just irrelevant
- Correct using `less` now as pager will be (without artefacts of pager extension)

  ```
  [pager]
  pager = less -FRX
  ```
- According to `hg help pager` in fresh HG (6.2), you can, with active pager, disable using it for some command(s)

> You can disable the pager for certain commands by adding them to the `pager. Ignore` list

i.e. have smth. like

```
  [pager]
  ignore = diff
```

and get diff totally without paging

- From the other side (contrary to the above point), you can use `--config`

> set/override config option (use 'section.name=value')

option on calling `hg diff` (when|if you'll have delta as working pager) and for simplicity create hg-alias for "hg diff with delta" like

```
  ddiff = diff --config pager.pager=delta $@
```

Comment: Question, does this work outside of Bash, given the `$@`?